# Basic Python if statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm learning Python and I'm trying to understand this line if I call f(-1):

```
x = 0
def f(x):
   if x < 0:
      return g(-x)
   else:
      return g(x)
def g(x):
      return 2*x + 3
```

If I call f(-1) I get 5. But I incorrectly interpret that I would get 1. This is my interpretation process:

Since x=-1 it should return g(-x). There is no def g(-x) though. However if it returns def g(x) then we should get 2*x+3, which is 1?

Don't know where I misunderstand.

Thanks

Comment: You may be interested by Python Tutor, a website that will help you to visualize your code  line by line. https://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of g as the function and x as input to the function.
Furthermore, x is also just like any other variable name.
This means I could instead rename the x variable in the g function to anything I want.
I could also call g anything I want.
Example:

```
def f(x):
   if x < 0:
      return grumpy_function(-x)
   else:
      return grumpy_function(x)

def grumpy_function(cool_value):
      return 2*cool_value + 3
```

Now try to walk through the logic using these above functions...
f(-1) causes the if statement x<0 to be true.
So we will execute the line `return grumpy_function(-x)`
We know that x=-1, so this means -x = -(-1) = 1.
Therefore cool_value is actually 1 not -1.
Now go to grumpy_function: 2*1+3 = 5.

Answer (score 1):

When you specify `def f(x)` or `def g(x)`, you're saying that, in the following context, `x` is going to be the name for the actual parameter of these two methods, regardless of the `x=0` defined outside.

That being said, the following lines are equivalent:

```
f(-1)
g(1)  # because if x < 0 is True
2 * 1 + 3
5
```

From your code, it is not exactly clear to me which of the `x`es you'd like to refer to the global `x=0` and which of them should refer to the function's parameter, like `-1` in your example. You should make this distinction yourself and name them differently, for example, `x` and `y`. As far as I know, if you name your function parameters the same as your global variables, you lose access to the global variables from within the function body (except for `globals` tricks).

Answer (score 1):

when call g(-x), in your case, it equals g(-(-1)), which is g(1)